# How to bind a function within itself in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, bind

i want to bind function within itself like
so that i can change state using this setState
help me resolve this
`function(response){
     this.function=this.function.bind(this)
     console.log(response)
 }`

Comment: is this an anonymous function or a class method?

Answer (score 1):

try this hopefully will work for you

```
axios.post(" http://${REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/facebook", { uid: user }).then((response) => {
        console.log('hello')
        if (response.data.success) {
            const { checked } = this.state;
            const newChecked = [...checked];
            newChecked.push(1)
            this.setState({ checked: newChecked });
            console.log(this.state.checked)
            history.push("/dashboard");
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: the function is in then/promise so it is showing error if i use const

Comment: can you add the complete function where you using this

Comment: loginRequest = axios.post(
        `http://${REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/facebook`,
        {
          uid:user
        }
      ).then(
       const login=(response)=>{
          console.log('hello')
          if(response.data.success){
            
            const { checked } = this.state;
            const newChecked = [...checked];
            newChecked.push(1)
            this.setState({
              checked: newChecked
            });
            console.log(this.state.checked)
            history.push("/dashboard");
          }
        }
      )

Comment: @user8523065 That is not valid code, and please add it to your actual question as a  properly formatted code block.

Comment: @user8523065 I have added the code in my answer try it will work hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Binding a function within itself is a confusing thing to do; you're modifying the function and it probably won't do what you expect the next time it's called. Your question is a classic example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

What you are probably looking for is described in the React docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance.

You have two options, call [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), or use an [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    /* Bind the value of this */
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      {/* Or use an arrow function */}
      <button onClick={() => this.myFunction()}>My button</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  to bind your response function

```js
function(response){
     //this.function=this.function.bind(this)
     console.log(response)
 }.bind(this)
```